# Cannot submit cmdbuffer using image ...

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to clear the the screen with a color, but I'm always getting an error
"Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (...) with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL.

And Actully i tried to modify some undefine values to depth_stenci_attachment optimal, but The only thing is I get is more of these errors. So is there a field,that is incorrectly filled, or I forget to fill?

So here is my full main.cpp Because I have no idea where the error could be.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>

#define DEBUG

#ifdef _WIN32
#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR 
#endif
#define KNOCH_JULIA 42
#include"window.h"

using namespace std;

#ifdef DEBUG
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
VkDebugReportCallbackEXT report;
void init_debug(vulkan *vulk);

PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT fvkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT fvkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT = VK_NULL_HANDLE;


VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL callback(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT flag, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT obj_t, uint64_t src_obj, size_t loc, int32_t msg_code, const char* layer_pref, const char* msg, void* user_data) {
    switch (flag) {
    case VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT:
        cout<<"error!"<<" "<< flag<<" source:"<<src_obj<<"location: "<<loc<<": "<< msg<<endl;
        break;
    case VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT:
        cout << "warning!" << obj_t << ": " << msg << endl;
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
void init_debug(vulkan *vulk) {
    fvkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(vulk->inst, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    fvkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(vulk->inst, "vkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT");
    if (nullptr == fvkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT || nullptr == fvkDestroyDebugReportCallbackEXT) {
        exit(-5);
    }
    VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    info.pfnCallback = callback;
    info.pNext = nullptr;
    info.flags = VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT;
    fvkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(vulk->inst, &info, nullptr, &report);
}
#endif

FILE *fileptr;
void initInstance(vulkan *vulk){
    vector<char*> ext;
    ext.push_back(VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
    ext.push_back(VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);

    VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 39);
    app_info.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 1);
    app_info.pApplicationName = "szar";
    app_info.pEngineName = "yayitstarts";
    app_info.pNext = nullptr;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
#ifdef DEBUG
    vector<char*>layers;
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker");
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation");
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation");
    //layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_vktrace");
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain");
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image");
    ext.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME);
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
    info.enabledLayerCount = layers.size();
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
#else
    info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
#endif
    info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    info.enabledExtensionCount = ext.size();
    info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ext.data();

    info.flags = 0;
    info.pNext = nullptr;

    vkCreateInstance(&info, nullptr, &(vulk->inst));
}
void getGPU(vulkan *vulk) {
    uint32_t dev_c=0;

    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vulk->inst,&dev_c,nullptr);
    VkPhysicalDevice *gpus=(VkPhysicalDevice*)malloc(sizeof(VkPhysicalDevice)*dev_c);
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(vulk->inst, &dev_c, gpus);
    vulk->gpu = gpus[0];
}
void createDevice(vulkan *vulk) {
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(vulk->gpu, &features);

    float prior[] = { 1.0f };

    uint32_t prop_c;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(vulk->gpu, &prop_c, nullptr);
    VkQueueFamilyProperties *props = (VkQueueFamilyProperties*)malloc(sizeof(VkQueueFamilyProperties)*prop_c);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(vulk->gpu, &prop_c, props);

    uint32_t index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < prop_c; i++) {
        VkBool32 supported;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(vulk->gpu, i, vulk->surface_struct.surface, &supported);
        if (props[i].queueFlags&VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT&&supported) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if (index == -1) {
        printf("no graphic queue family found");
        exit(-1);
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    uint32_t count;

    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, nullptr);
    vector<VkLayerProperties>layers_access(count);
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, layers_access.data());
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", layers_access[i].layerName);
    }
    uint32_t dev_count;
    vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(vulk->gpu, &dev_count, nullptr);
    vector<VkLayerProperties>layers_access_dev(count);
    vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(vulk->gpu, &dev_count, layers_access.data());
    for (int i = 0; i < dev_count; i++) {
        printf("dev: %s\n", layers_access_dev[i].layerName);
    }
#endif
    vulk->queue_fam_ind = index;
    int queue_count=1;

    vector<char*> ext;
    ext.push_back(VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME);

#ifdef DEBUG
    vector<char*> layers;
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker");
    layers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation");
#endif

    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queue_info = {};
    queue_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    queue_info.pQueuePriorities = prior;
    queue_info.queueCount = queue_count;
    queue_info.queueFamilyIndex = index;
    queue_info.flags = 0;
    queue_info.pNext = nullptr;

    VkDeviceCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
#ifdef DEBUG
    info.enabledLayerCount = layers.size();
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers.data();
#else
    info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
#endif
    info.pEnabledFeatures = &features;
    info.enabledExtensionCount = ext.size();
    info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ext.data();
    info.pQueueCreateInfos = &queue_info;
    info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
    info.pNext = nullptr;

    if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateDevice(vulk->gpu, &info, nullptr, &(vulk->device))) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    vulk->queue = (VkQueue*)malloc(sizeof(VkQueue)*queue_count);
    vkGetDeviceQueue(vulk->device, index, 0, &(vulk->queue[0]));
}
void createSwapchain(vulkan *vulk) {
    VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR capabilities;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(vulk->gpu, vulk->surface_struct.surface,&capabilities);

    uint32_t format_c;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(vulk->gpu, vulk->surface_struct.surface, &format_c, nullptr);
    VkSurfaceFormatKHR *formats = (VkSurfaceFormatKHR*)malloc(sizeof(VkSurfaceFormatKHR)*format_c);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(vulk->gpu, vulk->surface_struct.surface, &format_c, formats);

    uint32_t pres_mode_c;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(vulk->gpu, vulk->surface_struct.surface, &pres_mode_c, nullptr);
    VkPresentModeKHR *pres_modes = (VkPresentModeKHR*)malloc(sizeof(VkPresentModeKHR)*pres_mode_c);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(vulk->gpu, vulk->surface_struct.surface, &pres_mode_c, pres_modes);

    int pres_mode_i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pres_mode_c; i++) {
        if (pres_modes[i] == VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR) {
            pres_mode_i = i;
        }
    }

    vulk->surface_struct.extent = capabilities.currentExtent;
    vulk->image.color_format= formats[0].format;

    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    info.clipped = VK_TRUE;
    info.compositeAlpha = (VkCompositeAlphaFlagBitsKHR)capabilities.supportedCompositeAlpha;
    info.flags = 0;
    info.imageArrayLayers=1;
    info.imageColorSpace = formats[0].colorSpace;
    info.imageExtent = capabilities.currentExtent;
    info.imageFormat = formats[0].format;
    info.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    info.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    info.minImageCount = capabilities.minImageCount;
    info.oldSwapchain =VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    info.pNext = nullptr;
    info.pQueueFamilyIndices =&(vulk->queue_fam_ind);
    info.presentMode = pres_modes[pres_mode_i];
    info.preTransform = capabilities.currentTransform;
    info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;
    info.surface = vulk->surface_struct.surface;

    VkResult not_VK_SUCCESS = vkCreateSwapchainKHR(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, &(vulk->swapchain_struct.swapchain));
    if (not_VK_SUCCESS != VK_SUCCESS) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    vulk->swapchain_struct.format = formats[0].format;
}
void createImages(vulkan *vulk,Memory *depth_img_memory) {
    uint32_t img_c;
    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(vulk->device, vulk->swapchain_struct.swapchain, &img_c, nullptr);
    vulk->image.color_images = (VkImage*)malloc(sizeof(VkImage)*img_c);
    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(vulk->device, vulk->swapchain_struct.swapchain, &img_c, vulk->image.color_images);

    vulk->image_c = img_c;

    vulk->image.depth_images = (VkImage*)malloc(sizeof(VkImage));

    vulk->image.color_image_views=(VkImageView*)malloc(sizeof(VkImageView)*img_c);
    vulk->image.depth_image_views=(VkImageView*)malloc(sizeof(VkImageView));

    VkComponentMapping mapping = {};
    mapping.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R;
    mapping.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G;
    mapping.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B;
    mapping.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A;

    vulk->image.color_range = (VkImageSubresourceRange*)malloc(sizeof(VkImageSubresourceRange)*img_c);

    VkImageSubresourceRange range = {};
    range.aspectMask =VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    range.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    range.baseMipLevel = 0;
    range.layerCount = 1;
    range.levelCount = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < img_c; i++) {
        VkImageViewCreateInfo info = {};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
        info.components = mapping;
        info.flags = 0;
        info.format = vulk->swapchain_struct.format;
        info.image = (vulk->image.color_images)[i];
        info.pNext = nullptr;
        info.subresourceRange = range;
        info.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;

        vulk->image.color_range[i] = range;
        vkCreateImageView(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, &(vulk->image.color_image_views)[i]);
    }
    vulk->image.depth_range = (VkImageSubresourceRange*)malloc(sizeof(VkImageSubresourceRange));
    vulk->image.depth_range[0] = range;

    vector<VkFormat> depth_formats{ 
        VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT_S8_UINT,
        VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT,
        VK_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT,
        VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM_S8_UINT,
        VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM
    };

    VkFormat depth_format;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth_formats.size(); i++) {
        VkFormatProperties props;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(vulk->gpu, depth_formats[i], &props);
        if (props.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
            depth_format = depth_formats[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    vulk->image.depth_format = depth_format;
    VkImageCreateInfo img_info = {};
    img_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    img_info.arrayLayers = 1;
    img_info.extent.width = vulk->surface_struct.extent.width;
    img_info.extent.height = vulk->surface_struct.extent.height;
    img_info.extent.depth = 1;
    img_info.flags = 0;
    img_info.format = depth_format;
    img_info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    img_info.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    img_info.mipLevels = 1;
    img_info.pNext = nullptr;
    img_info.pQueueFamilyIndices = &(vulk->queue_fam_ind);
    img_info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1;
    img_info.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    img_info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    img_info.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    img_info.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;

    if (VK_SUCCESS!=vkCreateImage(vulk->device, &img_info, nullptr, &(vulk->image.depth_images)[0])) {
        printf("It not works");
    }
    VkMemoryRequirements req;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(vulk->device, (vulk->image.depth_images)[0], &req);

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(vulk->gpu, &(depth_img_memory->props));
    uint32_t mem_index=-2;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth_img_memory->props.memoryTypeCount; i++) {
        if (req.memoryTypeBits & (1 << i)) {
            if ((depth_img_memory->props.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags & VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT) == VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT) {
                mem_index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (mem_index == -2) {
        printf("no supported memorytype");
        exit(-2);
    }

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo mem_info = {};
    mem_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    mem_info.pNext = nullptr;
    mem_info.allocationSize = req.size;
    mem_info.memoryTypeIndex = mem_index;

    vkAllocateMemory(vulk->device, &mem_info, nullptr, &(depth_img_memory->dev_mem));
    vkBindImageMemory(vulk->device, (vulk->image.depth_images)[0], depth_img_memory->dev_mem, 0);

    VkComponentMapping mapping_d = {
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY,
        VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY,
    };

    range.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;


    VkImageViewCreateInfo img_view_info_d = {};
    img_view_info_d.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    img_view_info_d.components = mapping_d;
    img_view_info_d.flags = 0;
    img_view_info_d.format = depth_format;
    img_view_info_d.image = (vulk->image.depth_images)[0];
    img_view_info_d.pNext = nullptr;
    img_view_info_d.subresourceRange = range;
    img_view_info_d.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;

    if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateImageView(vulk->device, &img_view_info_d, nullptr, &(vulk->image.depth_image_views)[0])) {
        printf("huge pile of shit!!!");
        exit(-1);
    }

}
void createCommandPool(vulkan vulk,cmd_pool *pool, uint32_t cmd_buff_c) {
    VkCommandPoolCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
    info.flags = VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT|VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_TRANSIENT_BIT;
    info.pNext = nullptr;
    info.queueFamilyIndex = vulk.queue_fam_ind;

    vkCreateCommandPool(vulk.device, &info, nullptr, &(pool->pool));

    pool->cmd_buff_c = cmd_buff_c;
    pool->cmd_buffs = (VkCommandBuffer*)malloc(sizeof(VkCommandBuffer) * cmd_buff_c);

    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo cmd_info = {};
    cmd_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    cmd_info.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    cmd_info.commandPool = pool->pool;
    cmd_info.commandBufferCount = cmd_buff_c ;
    cmd_info.pNext = nullptr;

    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(vulk.device, &cmd_info, pool->cmd_buffs);
}
VkClearValue *clear;
void createFramebuffer(vulkan *vulk,VkExtent2D extent) {
    vulk->fbo = (VkFramebuffer*)malloc(sizeof(VkFramebuffer)*vulk->image_c);
    for (int i = 0; i < vulk->image_c; i++) {
        VkImageView *img_views = (VkImageView*)malloc(sizeof(VkImageView) * 2);
        img_views[0] = vulk->image.color_image_views[i];
        img_views[1] = vulk->image.depth_image_views[0];

        VkFramebufferCreateInfo info = {};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        info.attachmentCount = 2;
        info.pAttachments = img_views;
        info.width = extent.height;
        info.height = extent.width;
        info.layers = 1;
        info.renderPass = vulk->render_pass;
        info.flags = 0;
        info.pNext = nullptr;

        if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateFramebuffer(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, &(vulk->fbo[i]))) {
            printf("could not create framebuffer");
        }
    }
}


VkSemaphore *semaphores;

void createSemaphore(vulkan *vulk ,VkSemaphore *semaphore) {
    VkSemaphoreCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO;
    info.pNext = nullptr;
    info.flags = 0;

    vkCreateSemaphore(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, semaphore);
}
void createRenderPass(vulkan *vulk) {
    VkAttachmentDescription *descr = (VkAttachmentDescription*)malloc(sizeof(VkAttachmentDescription) * 2);

    VkAttachmentDescription color_descr = {};
    color_descr.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
    color_descr.format = vulk->image.color_format;
    color_descr.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    color_descr.initialLayout= VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    color_descr.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    color_descr.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    color_descr.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_descr.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_descr.flags = 0;

    VkAttachmentDescription depth_descr = {};
    depth_descr.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    depth_descr.format = vulk->image.depth_format;
    depth_descr.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    depth_descr.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    depth_descr.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    depth_descr.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depth_descr.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    depth_descr.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    depth_descr.flags = 0;

    *descr = color_descr;
    *(descr + 1) = depth_descr;

    VkAttachmentReference color_ref = {};
    color_ref.attachment = 0;
    color_ref.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference depth_ref = {};
    depth_ref.attachment = 1;
    depth_ref.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subp_descr = {};
    subp_descr.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subp_descr.pColorAttachments=&color_ref;
    subp_descr.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depth_ref;
    subp_descr.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
    subp_descr.pInputAttachments = nullptr;
    subp_descr.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
    subp_descr.pPreserveAttachments = nullptr;
    subp_descr.pResolveAttachments = nullptr;
    subp_descr.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subp_descr.flags = 0;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    info.attachmentCount = 2;
    info.pAttachments = descr;
    info.dependencyCount = 0;
    info.pDependencies = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    info.subpassCount = 1;
    info.pSubpasses = &subp_descr;
    info.flags = 0;
    info.pNext = nullptr;

    if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateRenderPass(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, &(vulk->render_pass))) {
        printf("Could not create render pass.");
    }
}

VkFence fence;

void createFences(vulkan *vulk) {
    VkFenceCreateInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO;
    info.pNext = nullptr;
    info.flags = 0;

    vkCreateFence(vulk->device, &info, nullptr, &fence);
}
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    vulkan vulk;
    Memory depth_memory;
    cmd_pool pool;

    initInstance(&vulk);
    getGPU(&vulk);
    Window window = Window();
    window.open(&vulk);
    createDevice(&vulk);

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.width = window.extent.width;
    viewport.height = window.extent.height;
    viewport.x = 0;
    viewport.y = 0;
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;
    init_debug(&vulk);
    createSwapchain(&vulk);
    createImages(&vulk, &depth_memory);
    createRenderPass(&vulk);
    createFramebuffer(&vulk,window.extent);

    semaphores= (VkSemaphore*) malloc(sizeof(VkSemaphore)*2);

    createSemaphore(&vulk, &semaphores[0]);
    createSemaphore(&vulk, &semaphores[1]);
    createFences(&vulk);

    createCommandPool(vulk,&pool,2);

    uint32_t img_pres;
    VkResult result;

    VkPresentInfoKHR info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    info.pImageIndices = &img_pres;
    info.pResults = &result;
    info.swapchainCount = 1;
    info.pSwapchains = &vulk.swapchain_struct.swapchain;
    info.waitSemaphoreCount =0;
    info.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
    info.pNext = nullptr;

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beg = {};
    beg.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beg.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;
    beg.pNext = nullptr;
    beg.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

    VkClearValue val[2];
    val[1] = { 0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f };
    val[0] = { 0.0f,0 };

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo render = {};
    render.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    render.clearValueCount = 2;
    render.framebuffer = vulk.fbo[0];
    render.pClearValues = val;
    render.pNext = nullptr;
    render.renderArea.offset = { 0,0 };
    render.renderArea.extent = { window.extent.height, window.extent.width };
    render.renderPass = vulk.render_pass;

    vkBeginCommandBuffer(pool.cmd_buffs[0], &beg);
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(pool.cmd_buffs[0], &render, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(pool.cmd_buffs[0]);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(pool.cmd_buffs[0]);

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo render_2 = {};
    render_2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    render_2.clearValueCount = 2;
    render_2.framebuffer = vulk.fbo[1];
    render_2.pClearValues = val;
    render_2.pNext = nullptr;
    render_2.renderArea = { 0,0,window.extent.height,window.extent.width };
    render_2.renderPass = vulk.render_pass;

    vkBeginCommandBuffer(pool.cmd_buffs[1], &beg);
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(pool.cmd_buffs[1], &render_2, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(pool.cmd_buffs[1]);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(pool.cmd_buffs[1]);

    VkSubmitInfo sub = {};
    sub.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    sub.commandBufferCount = 1;
    sub.pNext = nullptr;
    sub.pSignalSemaphores = nullptr;
    sub.pWaitDstStageMask = nullptr;
    sub.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
    sub.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
    sub.waitSemaphoreCount = 0;
    VkResult res=VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST;

    sub.pCommandBuffers = &pool.cmd_buffs[0];
    vkQueueSubmit(vulk.queue[0], 1, &sub, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    sub.pCommandBuffers = &pool.cmd_buffs[1];
    vkQueueSubmit(vulk.queue[0], 1, &sub, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

    while (window.running) {
        if (VK_SUCCESS != vkAcquireNextImageKHR(vulk.device, vulk.swapchain_struct.swapchain, UINT64_MAX, VK_NULL_HANDLE, fence, &img_pres)) {
            return -2;
        }
        vkWaitForFences(vulk.device, 1, &fence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
        vkResetFences(vulk.device, 1, &fence);vkQueueWaitIdle(vulk.queue[0]);

        sub.pCommandBuffers = &pool.cmd_buffs[img_pres];
        if (res == vkQueueSubmit(vulk.queue[0], 1, &sub, VK_NULL_HANDLE)) {
            printf("img: %d\n",res);
        }
        cout << hex << vulk.image.depth_images[0] << endl;
        vkQueuePresentKHR(vulk.queue[0], &info);
        window.run();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Update your SDK. There is even no `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image` layer since 1.0.42.0. And you know, there was probably a bunchload of bugfixes.

2) You are enabling layers in wrong order. Use the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` meta-layer instead of doing it manually (also avoids problem in 1 trying to use obsoleted layer).

3) I see many errors in your code. Layers do not necessarily have full coverage yet (and another uncought error may cause to show another error down the road that does not make sense without the context).

E.g. no synchronization (your semaphores are unused there), many memory leaks (due to C style programming), assuming there will be at least two swapchain images, not checking `VkResult`s...

4) I cannot reproduce it with your code. Firstly I get a problem with having only one swapchain image and the code not expecting it (mentioned in 3). After fixing that I get error about `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` getting more images than allowed (<s>driver</s> layer bug if using `VkPresentInfoKHR::pResults`). Workarounding that I get no error messages.

Comment: Jut F.Y.I. it's not a driver bug with `VkPresentInfo::pResults`, it's from unique_objects validation layer. I reported it couple hours ago here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/1670.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your code exhaustively, but the renderpass says that both attachments are initially in UNDEFINED layout, transition to COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL/DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL, and then finally to PRESENT_SRC/DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL. That seems correct, and the validation layers appear to be ignoring the renderpass initialLayout settings. If you're seeing this on the most recent version of the SDK, please file a bug at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers.